# Implement ripple effects on imageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to implement the ripple effect in an Imagebutton.

**activty_main.xml**

```
        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/idbuttonsix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/iconagift"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
```

I have try to implementing this code, I don't get the ripple effect on the ImageButton on touch:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

and this

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

I am looking for someone who can help me step by step.

**ripple_effect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorAccent">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#4CAF50" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: On which Android version are you running the app on? Also post your ripple_effect.xml

Comment: `android:clickable="true"`  try this

Comment: @NabinBhandari  This app - minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 26

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/idbuttonsix"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Note that i have removed the "src" tag here and have just used "background" attribute. This would definitely work for you to give ripple effect to this button.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the src tag from the imageview, and try adding this background (and not foreground):

android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: Thank you, @Rabillo but how to do it...? I need this icone "@drawable/iconagift"

Comment: how about you enclose your button inside a frame layout: you set the background of your framelayout as your drawable, and background of your button as android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score -1):

[image]

To use this library (android 9+): [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)

**Integration**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
  android:id="@+id/more"
  android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/more2"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  rv_centered="true">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Add your dependency inside your  App `Gridle` file.

Comment: yes it works, but it show bigger circles, when i close activity

Comment: they are too big

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155716/discussion-between-bucky-and-gowthaman-m).